# How do I fix my laptop getting redirect loops?

Tags: networking, browser

I've been trying to access my university's website/learning management system for the past week. For some reason, after typing in my username and password in the login page, I'm sent to a redirect page saying

Checking your browser before accessing "website name".
This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.

Redirecting…

DDoS protection by Cloudflare

However, I am not redirected further and the page keeps refreshing showing the same message. I tried on other computers or phones in the house connected to the same network and it works fine on them, but my personal laptop keeps running into this problem. I've tried on different browsers and reinstalling the drivers to my network adapter. I don't have this problem with other websites, just the one for my university. Does anyone have any other ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying it in a different browser. For example, if you are currently using Chrome, try Firefox and vice versa.

Make sure the date/time and timezone settings on your computer are correct. That is frequently the cause of the problem.

If you are using a VPN, you may have to temporarily disable it in order to gain access to those sites.

Comment: I usually use Opera, but I also tried logging in using Chrome, Edge, and Firefox, but I ran into the same problem. My time and date settings are synced up to the network, and my time zone is set to the right one. I tried using a VPN (didn't have one before), and I surprisingly got past the redirect loop. Although I don't  really want to rely on it, is there any other way? Thanks for answering btw.